# Objective C: Passing a NSStringFromSelector to another object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, selector

I am trying to pass a selector from class A to class B in order to later call that function but whenever I try to use the selector from class B, it no longer exists. The only thing I see in the debugger is that the string in class B no longer exists.

Class A

```
[classB save:@selector(otherMethodInClassA:) target:self]
```

Class B

```
@property(retain) (NSString*)mySelectorString
@property(retain) (id)someObj
-(void)save:(SEL)selector target:(id)obj
{
    mySelectorString = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
    //I've also tried the following
    mySelectorString = [NSStringWithFormat @"%@", NSStringFromSelector(selector)];
    someObj = obj;
}
-(void)useSelector
{
    [someObj performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(mySelectorString)]; //tells me its a bad exec
}
```

Comment: use prepare for segue to pass value.

Comment: Your sample selector takes a single parameter, but when you invoke it, you don't provide one.  Double-check the selector signature.

Comment: @balkaransingh I'm using cocoa, not cocoa touch. Not sure how prepareforsegue would work in this case

Comment: @Avi I'm a bit confused with what you mean in that case. performSelector takes in a selector parameter, the parameter I'm providing is `NSSelectorFromString(mySelectorString)`

Comment: @David: Your selector is `otherMethodInClassA:`, which implies that it takes a parameter. However, when you call it using `performSelector:`, you do not pass that parameter to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a block?

In your classB:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void(^block)(void);

- (void)registerCallbackBlock:(void(^)(void))block {
    _block = block;
}

- (void)callBlock {
    _block();
}
```

In your classA:

```
- (void)someMethod {
   [classB registerCallbackBlock:^{
       [classA someOtherMethod:args...];
    }];
}
```